# How can pass data from Adapter to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

How can pass data between `adapter` and `fragment`?

My adapter:

```
finalHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        finalHolder.spinner.setSelection(position);
        selState = finalHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println(selState);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key", selState);
        Log.i("BUNDLE", bundle.toString());
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }
});
```

My fragment:

```
public  class MyListFragment extends Fragment{

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);

        /*Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String strtext = bundle.getString("key", " ");
        System.out.println(strtext);*/
        System.out.println("prima ancora");

        Bundle arguments = this.getArguments();
        System.out.println("prima");
        if (arguments != null) {
            System.out.println("dopo");

            //String userId = arguments.getString("key");
                //System.out.println("finalmente:"+userId);
             user = getArguments().getString("Key");


        } 

}
```

Comment: use listeners. when you make adapter can pass reference of listener and use that listener to pass data back to fragment

Answer (score 2):

You can use Interface to pass data from the adapter to the fragment, and generally, you can find it here:[Java - Interface](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm)

In your case you can implement an interface like this:

```
Public Interface YourInterfaceName{
    void onItemSelected(String key, String Value);
}
```

in your fragment you have to implement your intrface:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements YourInterface
{
    YourAdapter.setOnItemSelected(this);
}
```

and finlay in your adapter do this:

```
public class Adapter
{
    public void setOnItemSelected(YourInterface yourIntrface)
    {
         this.yourIntrface = yourIntrface;
    }
    .......
    finalHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
.....
     //instead of creating instance of fragment do this:
     yourInterface.onItemSelected(yourKey, value);     
}
```